# unable to send mail test zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I want to setup email notification using zabbix. When I click *Test* I get notification

> Access denied to remote resource: Remote access denied: 501

My SMTP config:

- `smtp.office365.com`
- port : 587
- connection security : STARTTLS
- username : `myemail@domain.com`
- password : (redacted)

When using GMail I get same notification.

Comment: Can your Zabbix server resolve `smtp.office365.com`? Can Office365 resolve the IP address it sees when your Zabbix server tries to send a message? I strongly suspect you have at least one DNS issue here

Answer (score -3):

works change smtp hello to : smtp.office365.com

Comment: According to the text in the question, this appears to be what you already are using.

Comment: And if you really mean the SMTP HELO command, something is seriously wrong; the HELO argument should be your client's name, not the name of the server you are connecting to.